# Linux DNS: expand name with a choosen domain

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, hosts

I need to expand a random name with a choosen domain. Example: nslookup abc 127.0.0.1 -> should look for abc.domainchoosen.dom.

Suggestions?

Comment: Linux version? Distro?

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do?  The thing you want it to point at is an email address.  Are you looking for the default DNS suffix?  This makes no sense at all as written.

Comment: forgive my typo! I mean abc.domainchoosen.com

Answer (score 5):

Add the desired domain to the `search` line in `/etc/resolv.conf`. For example:

```
search example.com
```

Comment: I did it but wget yy.domain.com downloads domain.com and *not* yy.domain.com, where am I wrong? Suggestions?

Comment: @Conl That's a completely separate question.